# Maven tycho-surefire-plugin fails with return code 13

Tags: maven, tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

I have a OSGI-bundle and now want to create a testing bundle for it. As the existing bundle uses Tycho, I also wanted to do testing the Eclipse/Tycho-way by using the tycho-surefire-plugin.

As far as I understood, testing the Eclipse-way means, that each bundle has a corresponding bundle containing all relevant test cases.

So I created a new bundle "xyz.tests" with the following pom:

```
    <artifactId>xyz.tests</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.21.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I also created the other standard files of tycho/OSGI-projects
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %Bundle-Name
Bundle-SymbolicName: xyz
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Fragment-Host: zyx
Import-Package: org.junit;version="4.11.0"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

build.properties

```
output.. = bin/
source.. = src/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
           OSGI-INF/,\
           .
```

and OSGI-INF/l10n/bundle.properties

```
# META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Bundle-Name=XYZ Tests
```

Then I wrote a "test-case" as I first wanted to check if my eclipse-test-plugin if configured correctly

```
package xyz.tests.xyz;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class XYZTest {

    @Test
    public void testClasstest() {
        assertEquals("Tests", true, true);
    }
}
```

When I run *mvn package* as a goal, everything compiles and packages without errors. Then I ran *mvn integration-test* as goal (this is the part where tycho-surefire starts working). There I get an error-message which provides no useful information for me:

```
[INFO] --- tycho-surefire-plugin:0.21.0:test (default-test) @ xyz.tests ---
[INFO] Expected eclipse log file: /pathXYZ/target/work/data/.metadata/.log
[INFO] Command line:
    [/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java, -Dosgi.noShutdown=false, -Dosgi.os=linux, -Dosgi.ws=gtk, -Dosgi.arch=x86_64, -Dosgi.clean=true, -jar, /home/erdi/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/1.3.0.v20130327-1440/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar, -data, /pathXYZ/target/work/data, -install, /pathXYZ/target/work, -configuration, /pathXYZ/target/work/configuration, -application, org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest, -testproperties, /pathXYZ/target/surefire.properties]
xyz: Hello World!!

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
xyz: Goodbye World!!
An error has occurred. See the log file
/pathXYZ/target/work/configuration/1432736234573.log.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 26.050s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 27 16:17:16 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 69M/362M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.21.0:test (default-test) on project xyz.tests: An unexpected error occured (return code 13). See log for details. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

The "xyz: Hello/Goodbye World" messages are messages that are printed when the bundle I wanted to test starts/stops. This means, that my configuration seems to be okay when the bundle starts, but immediately after it an error occurs. Unfortunately looking into the logfile also reveals nothing useful:

```
!SESSION 2015-05-27 16:17:14.238 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_75
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties /pathXYZ/target/work/data -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties /pathXYZ/target/surefire.properties

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-05-27 16:17:15.891
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3217)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.isValidJUnit4Test(JUnit4TestChecker.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:83)
    ... 28 more
```

So I know that a null pointer exception occurs, but I have no idea why/where.

I think it would really help to see the whole error-path which is hidden behind "... 28 more" but I have no idea how to see it...

I am also not completely sure if I configured everything correctly, as I found no useful tutorial and more or less looked at the testing-codebase of other eclipse-projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the origin of my problem:

I was using tycho v0.21.0 where this issue was reported as a bug (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=369266) and got fixed with tycho v0.22.0.

Changing to the version property for the tycho-surefire-plugin solved the problem.